# For random generating string how to fix "for loop initial declaration used outside c99 mode"?

Tags: c, string, unix, random

Random string generator using C programming. How to fix "for loop initial declaration used outside c99 mode"?

```
void generate_string(char **string){

    srand(time(NULL));
    int numOfChars=rand()%9+1;
    int i=0;
    char temp[numOfChars];
     for(i=0;i<numOfChars;i++){
        char tmp ='A'+rand()%26;
        temp[i]=tmp;

     }
     temp[i+1]='\0';
    strcpy(*string,temp);
}


    int main()
    {
    char *str;
    str= (char*)malloc(11 * sizeof(char));
    generate_string(&str);
    int len=(int)strlen(str);
        printf("Random String:");
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++) { 
        printf("%c",*str);
        str++;
       } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile with `-std=c99` option in GCC.

Comment: or move the definition of `i` out of `for(int i=0;i<len;i++)`

Comment: In general, `srand(time(NULL));` should be near the start of `main` and called only once, but since you only call `generate_string` once, that won't matter here.

Comment: `temp[i+1]='\0';` should be `temp[i]='\0';` because the loop ends with `i` incremented. Your array is broken. Even without that mistake, the array is too short to hold the terminator, try `char temp[numOfChars+1];`